# Problems with recursive array.push()

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion

I have the following array of objects with GoogleShoppingFeed-Categories:

```
[{
    id: 914,
    path: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires > Bekleidung'
},
{
    id: 910,
    path: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires > Bekleidung > Anzüge'
},
{
    id: 2904,
    path: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires > Bekleidung > Anzüge > Anzüge & Hosenanzüge'
}]
```

I want to split() the path string by ' > ' and build up a new array like this. The length of path array is unknown:

```
[{
    id: 914,
    path: [{
        counter: 0,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires'
        },
        {
        counter: 1,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung'
        }
    ]
},{
    id: 910,
    path: [{
        counter: 0,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires'
        },
        {
        counter: 1,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung'
        },
        {
        counter: 2,
        partialPath: 'Anzüge'
        }
    ]
},{
    id: 2904,
    path: [{
        counter: 0,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung & Accessoires'
        },
        {
        counter: 1,
        partialPath: 'Bekleidung'
        },
        {
        counter: 2,
        partialPath: 'Anzüge'
        },
        {
        counter: 3,
        partialPath: 'Anzüge & Hosenanzüge'
        }
    ]
},
...
]
```

This is my current approach:

```
export interface GPartialCategory {
  id: number;
  path: [{
    counter: number;
    partialPath: string;
  }];
}

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

  constructor() { }

  async getAllGoogleCategories(): Promise<GPartialCategory[]> {
    const repo = getRepository(GCategoryEntity, 'default');
    const allCategories = await repo.find({ order: { path: 'ASC' } });
    let result: any[] = [];
    for (const category of allCategories) {
      result.push(this.recursivePush(category));
    }
    return result;
  }

  recursivePush(category: GCategoryDto): GPartialCategory {
    let result: GPartialCategory;
    const fragments = category.path.split(' > ', 2);
    const firstValue = fragments[0];
    const rest = fragments[1];

    result = ({ id: category.id, path: [{ counter: 0, partialPath: firstValue }] });

    let i = 1;
    while (!!rest) {
      const restFragments = rest.split(' > ', 2);
      const value = restFragments[0];
      const nextRest = restFragments[1];
      result.path.push({ counter: i, partialPath: value });
      i++;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

As you can see, this leads into JavaScript heap out of memory, because the const rest is always not empty.

Thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe recursion is the answer here. You want to map through each path object, and create a new array inside each object. This can be done using the `.map()` array method.

```
async getAllGoogleCategories(): Promise<GPartialCategory[]> {
  const repo = getRepository(GCategoryEntity, 'default');
  const allCategories = await repo.find({ order: { path: 'ASC' } });
  return allCategories.map(category=>{
    const pathArr = category.path.split(' > ');
    const path = pathArr.map((partialPath, i)=>({counter:i, partialPath}));
    return {...category, path }
  })
};
```

Comment: Thx, that´s great